# Conditionally navigate to new view in swiftui

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I tried to navigate to my user view in login submit function with swiftui.

```
struct LoginUIView: View {
    ...
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ...
            Button(action: {
                self.login(name: self.name, pass: self.pass)
            }) {
                Text("Login")
                    .padding()
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .cornerRadius(4.0)
                    .background(Color("light-green"))
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }

    func login(name: String, pass: String) {
        // auth with name and pass
        // then try to conditionally navigate to specific view
        if ... {
            // navigate to user view
        }

        if ... {
            // navigate to other view
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [swiftUI: Navigate to Home screen after Login Completed. Navigating Views by Button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58537359/swiftui-navigate-to-home-screen-after-login-completed-navigating-views-by-butt)

Comment: @Asperi It seems must create a navigationLink, is there a way to direct to navigate conditionally?

Comment: @ccd Why not create 2 NavigationLinks, one for each of the conditionals?

Comment: @RazvanS. How to create many navigationLinks in one button?

Comment: @ccd No, you cannot I was talking about reframing the problem, but I don't think there's an easy way to do it in this situation. But you can put your login method logic in the destination of your navigation link. Checkout this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57606290/change-navigationlink-destination-conditionally-in-swiftui